# insert variable into hex string

Tags: python, string, hex

There is a hex data in client :

```
MESSAGE = "\x16\x01\x12\x03\x1b\x14\x30\x23\x80\x00\x03\xe8\x00\x00\x00\x00"
s.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

and server would show :

```
16 01 12 03 1b 14 30 23 80 00 03 e8 00 00 00 00
```

but when I want to use variable and for loop to increase the last number

```
for i in range(times):
     i += 1
     i = format(i, '02x')
MESSAGE = "\x16\x01\x12\x03\x1b\x14\x30\x23\x80\x00\x03\xe8\x00\x00\x00"+i
s.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

server would show:

```
16 01 12 03 1b 14 30 23 80 00 03 e8 00 00 00 30 32
```

The "+i" become ASCII....

So how should I do to make the server show:

```
16 01 12 03 1b 14 30 23 80 00 03 e8 00 00 00 01
16 01 12 03 1b 14 30 23 80 00 03 e8 00 00 00 02
16 01 12 03 1b 14 30 23 80 00 03 e8 00 00 00 03
...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't format the number, just create a character with that code using the `chr` function.

And rather than adding `1` to `i` in the loop, just change the range of the loop.

```
for i in range(1, times+1):
    i = chr(i)
    MESSAGE = "\x16\x01\x12\x03\x1b\x14\x30\x23\x80\x00\x03\xe8\x00\x00\x00"+i
    s.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a string pattern like `"\x%02x" % i`.

Comment: You misunderstand the question.

Comment: `\x` is for literal hex codes, it isn't processed after formatting.